# Running python script inside activated virtual env in a bash script

Tags: python, linux, anaconda, virtualenv

I have created a virtual environment with conda. In a bash script, I want to activate it and then run a python script inside that virtual environment. I am using the following method:

```
#!/bin/bash
conda activate my_env   
python my_script.py
```

But, this is not working and I get the following error:

```
CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.  
To initialize your shell, run
$ conda init <SHELL_NAME>
```

I have installed some python packages inside my virtual environment so if I use  full/explicit path to Python executable in my_env rather than activating my_env then I can not use those python packages. What should I do?

Comment: Please include more details to your question, what error you got, it's seems you miss `conda activate my_env`   command too.

Comment: To solve problem add the full path to python in the `my_env`

Comment: What do you mean? how can I do that?

Comment: There’s no need to activate; just provide the full/explicit path to your Python executable.  And I’m a little confused, you mention Linux and Bash, and then init powershell ... is powershell not a Win application?

Comment: My mistake. I am using Linux. So, I do not need powershell. Your solution is very good but I have installed some python packages inside my virtual environment and when I use your method then it can not find those packages. I have updated question

Comment: Thanks for the update; I must disagree with you.  I use this method myself when running scripts via cron, without activating the conda env.  Have you tried it?

Comment: I don't use anaconda, but I'm sure there must be some version of `conda run --env my_env python my_script.py`. It should run a single command (in this case, `python my_script.py`) after activating `my_env` in a subshell.

Comment: Nevermind, looks like they removed `conda run` for whatever reason: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/2682

Comment: Check `conda --version`, if fails you could try `export PATH="/opt/conda/bin:$PATH"`,  target `conda.sh` file. **on terminal**

Comment: conda --version works fine

Comment: Then there's no need to specify conda environment path, in `.sh` file, if there's no error check if your python code, has a print statement or anything similar, as there's no error it's have to work.